# How can I optimize this script to work better in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple script that does the following:

- Monitors a column (from two different worksheets)
- The column monitored is a data validation drop down menu
- Depending on the category chosen, the script will create a second depedent row of drop downs in the cell next to it.
- When the original monitored column is cleared, the dependent drop down is cleared as well
- The script pulls from a hidden "Data" worksheet

The script does tend to run a little slow, and I am wondering if there is any way to clean up/optimize it. Maybe use different functions? I am not great with coding at all, but managed to piece this together using videos/other sheets examples.

Thanks in advance.

```
    function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 6 && activeCell.getRow() > 4 && ss.getName() == "TxsSheet1"){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    
    if(activeCell.isBlank()){            
    }
      var categories = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();    
      var categoriesIndex = categories[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
    
      if(categoriesIndex != 0){          
        var validationRange = datass.getRange(2, categoriesIndex, datass.getLastRow());
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);    
      }
  } 
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 6 && activeCell.getRow() > 4 && ss.getName() == "TxsSheet2"){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    
    if(activeCell.isBlank()){            
    }
      var categories = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();    
      var categoriesIndex = categories[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
    
      if(categoriesIndex != 0){          
        var validationRange = datass.getRange(2, categoriesIndex, datass.getLastRow());
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);    
      }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ["TxsSheet1", "TxsSheet2"]
  if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart > 4 && ~shts.indexOf(sh.getName())) {
    const dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Data");
    const activeCell = sh.getActiveCell();
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    let categories = dsh.getRange(1, 1, 1, dsh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    let categoriesIndex = categories[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;

    if (categoriesIndex != 0) {
      let validationRange = dsh.getRange(2, categoriesIndex, dsh.getLastRow());
      let validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, thank you for the prompt response. I get a ReferenceError: e is not defined error when running this

Comment: You cannot run it from the script editor.  I debug these things by editing the sheet. Oh I just notice I didn't put e in the declaration.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. I appreciate your help.